# I want to read json file data with specific json object array one by one using foreach loop in c#

Tags: c#, json

Can someone help me with the following:

I have the following JSON that is composed of several arrays of AA, BB, CC objects and each of these has its corresponding KEY "ts" and VALUE "value" objects.

```
{
  "AA": [
    {
      "ts": 1636862399574,
      "value": "2021-11-14 00:57:25.049983"
    },
    {
      "ts": 1636862398995,
      "value": "2021-11-14 00:57:24.049979"
    }
  ],
  "BB": [
    {
      "ts": 1636862399574,
      "value": "16183.8"
    },
    {
      "ts": 1636862398995,
      "value": "16183.8"
    }
  ],
  "CC": [
    {
      "ts": 1636862399574,
      "value": "0.0"
    },
    {
      "ts": 1636862398995,
      "value": "0.0"
    }
  ]
}
```

My code snippet in C #:

```
List<List<DateTime>> ArrayAA;
List<List<double>> ArrayBB;
List<List<double>> ArrayCC;

        for (int i = 0; i < devices.Count; i++)
        {
                var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                if (data != null)
                {                                
                  // Then deserialize your json to Dictionary<string, List<MyObject>>
                  var myDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<MyObject>>>(JSONdata);               
                  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<MyObject>> entry in myDictionary)
                   {
                      foreach (var obj in entry.Value)
                      {
                          Console.WriteLine($"{entry.Key} -> ts: {obj.TS}, value: {obj.Value}");
                          ArrayAA[i].Add(obj.value);
                          ArrayBB[i].Add(obj.value);
                          ArrayCC[i].Add(obj.value);
                      }
                   }
                }
        }
```

My code is not working, I need to read all the values ​​at once for each AA, BB, CC.

It's possible?

Comment: Yes...deserialize to dictionary of strings and lisylt of objects

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: The error displayed:: Exception raised: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Comment: Each of the item [AA] or BB is an array... not an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first deserialize your object to a dictionary. This way you can iterate over each of the keys you have. Once you have the dictionary... you can print the values however you like.

this is an example that shows you how to access the values of each of the keys, "AA", "BB", "CC" etc.

```
// Build your object class first.
public class MyObject
{
    [JsonProperty("ts")]
    public long TS { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

// Then deserialize your json to Dictionary<string, List<MyObject>> 
var myDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<MyObject>>>(jsonText);
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<MyObject>> entry in myDictionary)
{
    foreach (var obj in entry.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{entry.Key} -> ts: {obj.TS}, value: {obj.Value}");
    }
}

List<DateTime> arrayAA = myDictionary["AA"].Select(x => DateTime.Parse(x.Value)).ToList();
List<double> arrayBB = myDictionary["BB"].Select(x => double.Parse(x.Value)).ToList();
List<double> arrayCC = myDictionary["CC"].Select(x => double.Parse(x.Value)).ToList();

// Prints the following output
AA -> ts: 1636862399574, value: 2021-11-14 00:57:25.049983
AA -> ts: 1636862398995, value: 2021-11-14 00:57:24.049979
BB -> ts: 1636862399574, value: 16183.8
BB -> ts: 1636862398995, value: 16183.8
CC -> ts: 1636862399574, value: 0.0
CC -> ts: 1636862398995, value: 0.0
```

**UPDATE** - How to add items?
if you want to add items to the data... you will need to know which Key you want to add the item to.

```
string key = "AA";
if (myDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
{
    myDictionary[key].Add(new MyObject() { TS = 651651651651, Value = "abc" });
}

// or get only the values and save them in separate arrays? use LINQ
string[] arrayAA = myDictionary["AA"].Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
string[] arrayBB = myDictionary["BB"].Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: It works 100%. This is the optimized solution that I was looking for. Thank very much :)

Comment: How can I fill each of the ArrayXX [i] arrays?

Comment: @ingezone see my update above.

Comment: Please see my updated C # code snippet.

Comment: @ingezone that will not work. you are initializing the arrays within the loop.. it will get overwritten each time. Think about what you are trying to do first.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, now it's correct.

Comment: You cant add values to AA, BB and CC when iterating over each object separately. Use LINQ like i mentioned to get the values (and cast them to how you need to) after the for loops.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, you can give me an example.

Comment: @ingezone Added the lines in my original answer. should solve your List issues.

Comment: When executing it shows this error:   error CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation

Comment: I tested the code before ppsting.. besides, it answers your question u posted

Comment: Finally I was able to find the problem, I made a small change in my code and now your solution worked 100%. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, one of which is to use the `JObject` class

```
JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);
if (data != null)
{
    var itemsA = data["AA"].Select(i => i["value"]);
    foreach(var item in itemsA)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Value: " + item);
    }
    //and BB and CC.....................................
}
```

OR

```
JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);
Console.WriteLine("Value: " + data["AA"][0]["value"]);
Console.WriteLine("Value: " + data["AA"][1]["value"]);
//.......................................
Console.WriteLine("Value: " + data["BB"][0]["value"]);
```

You can either use dynamic data type or pack in specific classes.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create class based on the json string and the deserialize to that class

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;



public class MyRootClass
{
    public List<AA> AA { get; set; }
    public List<AA> BB { get; set; }
    public List<AA> CC { get; set; }
}

public class AA
{
    public long ts { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class BB
{
    public long ts { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class CC
{
    public long ts { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}



string json = "yourJson";

var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyRootClass>(json);
```

and to read it. loop over each list in the myobject

```
foreach (var item in myObject.AA)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.value);
    Console.WriteLine(item.ts);
}
```